# key prop warning on react tbody

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting a

Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

on the tbody line and I'm not sure why. Every child of this component has keys and from the looks of it, it is not warning in the LocationListItem component. I feel like I just don't understand something.

```
    <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>PostalCode</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Tax Rate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody key="tbody">
            {stores.map((item: any, index: number) => {
                if (item.LTPMerchantId == null) {
                    item.LTPMerchantId = "";
                }
                if (item.ChaseOrbitalMerchantId == null) {
                    item.ChaseOrbitalMerchantId = "";
                }
                if (item.CYBSMerchantId == null) {
                    item.CYBSMerchantId = "";
                }
                return (
                    <>
                        {
                            <LocationListItem key={index} LTPMerchantId={item.LTPMerchantId} ChaseOrbitalMerchantId={item.ChaseOrbitalMerchantId} CYBSMerchantId={item.CYBSMerchantId} alert={props.alert} StoreId={item.StoreId} HoursId={item.HoursId} AddressId={item.AddressId} Name={item.Name} Address={item.Address} Address2={item.Address2} City={item.City} State={item.State} PostalCode={item.PostalCode} PhoneNumber={item.PhoneNumber} TaxRate={item.TaxRate} Latitude={item.Latitude} Longitude={item.Longitude} Radius={item.Radius} Sunday={item.Sunday} Monday={item.Monday} Tuesday={item.Tuesday} Wednesday={item.Wednesday} Thursday={item.Thursday} Friday={item.Friday} Saturday={item.Saturday} />
                        }
                    </>
                );
            })}
        </tbody>
    </Table>
```

Comment: Remove the fragment, `<>`, `</>`, and `key="tbody"` on `tbody`.

Comment: worked thx ggorlen!